# background-attachment fixed chrome lag

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, lag

I have problems again with chrome design on my site. When scrolling no loss of fps and lag on the page. I've been giving it a lot of laps to find the real culprit of the problem is the property `background-attachment: fixed;`.

I tried to solve with the solution of this page and has not worked for me.

https://petersproblems.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/background-attachment-fixed-causing-lag-when-scrolling/

I would like to use `background-attachment: fixed;` and no lag, is there any solution?

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(imagen/fondo.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Comment: The only solution that kinda worked for me was this plugin https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll. I think you have to change (control) scroll on `-webkit-` browsers to fix that parallax jumpiness. But if there is other solutions i would like to hear it.

Comment: It's a shame that the most used browser in the world has so many problems in design issues. You subtract Libet. It also happens with shadows.

Firefox in this respect no problems whatsoever, Edge and IE10 either.

Comment: http://www.stephenfry.com/
Here I leave a web with the background and the same problem of lag

Comment: I fought with this and found that chrome does not allow fractional margins (used in parallax scrolling) but defaults to units of 1. This is partially why background attachment-fixed is so bung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add-

```
transform:translatez(0);
-webkit-transform:translatez(0);
```

Comment: Thanks! After playing with it, I discovered that when the fix is applied to `body`, it breaks `position:fixed`, but only applying it to the bulk content element that should scroll fixes everything. Well, not entirely; if the DOM is updated, the stutter comes back momentarily, but still much better than without the fix. I also only kept the `-webkit-` version because Firefox doesn't have the problem.